# object%20Object in GET url Angular 13 error 404 not found

Tags: angular, typescript, http

So i am trying to build an online-shop with Angular and Spring Boot and I've run into an issue, whenever i call the productService method in **ngOnInit** I get the following error in the console
[image]

instead of the route: **/products/product/:id** I am getting an object and I don't know why is that.

Basically what i am trying to do is: I have a list of products and if the user clicks on any of the product, to be redirected to a new page which contains some info about that specific product.

Here's the code:

**product-page.component.ts**

```
export class ProductPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private productService: ProductServiceService) { 
    this.product = new Product();
  }

  product: Product;
  productId;
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.params.subscribe(data => {
      this.productId = data['id'];
      this.productService.findProductById(this.productId).subscribe(data => {
        this.product = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'products/product/:id', component: ProductPageComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

The path for this Component is **products/product/:id**

**product.service.ts**

```
export class ProductServiceService {

  url: string = environment.apiBaseUrl; //localhost:8080
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllProducts() {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(`${this.url}/products`);
  }
  findProductById(productId: number) {
    return this.http.get<Product>(`${this.http}/product/${productId}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: given that you are not constructing the URL in any of the code you pasted here, you should also include the code for the `productService.findProductById`, since that is where you are making your http request

Comment: @Edward Yes i completely missed that one, updated the post

Comment: ``return this.http.get<Product>(`${this.http}/product/${productId}`);`` this.http is an object. Try something like `${this.url}/product/${productId}` instead.

Comment: @BálintRéthy oh yes I put this.http instead of this.url, it works well now, thanks ! gotta be more focused in the future ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the comment section the solution is to change `this.http` to `this.url` in line `` return this.http.get<Product>(`${this.http}/product/${productId}`); `` => `` return this.http.get<Product>(`${this.url}/product/${productId}`); `` of product.service.ts.